# How to partially mock an object in javascript / node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, sinon

I'm using Sinon, and want to mock only some of the methods of an object, but the mock returns undefined for all methods.  Is there anyway to get the calls to pass through by default?

```
var sinon=require('sinon');
var util = require('util');
var mockedUtil = sinon.mock(util);

util.isNumber(1); // true
mockedUtil.isNumber(1); // exception because isNumber is undefined
```

Comment: I can't find it in the documentation, but you can use `mockedUtil.object.isNumber`

Comment: do you really need a mock or is a stub good enough? When to use mocks: http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I'm passing the mock into my code under test, and the my code calls the mock.  I want those calls to succeed.